# Should i registerd all component to app.js or import in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Now i have two option to inject my component to my application.

> 1. first way in app.js

```
Vue.component(
"notice-master-component",
require("./components/site/communication/Notice/MasterComponent.vue")
```

);

> 2. in any vue component where the component needs it

```
    import NoticeMasterComponent from "../Notice/MasterComponent.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    NoticeMasterComponent ,
```

in both way i can use the component

Which one is better or recommended?

Comment: personal prefference, opinion based question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way is registering the component globally, so maybe register those components that you wish to use globally (in many different views for example). Then you don't have to go trough the trouble of importing it every time you want to use it.

Second way is better if you only need to import it only once. With lazy loading it's even better to not import every component that the user may not ever see.

Comment: You said perfect! @artoju

Comment: Do you know the way how i can lazy load every component with its import only? I mean with separated bundle for every component and one package bundle. @artoju

Comment: @John I usually just lazy load routes. Documentation here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html